# What to tell newcomers posting Not-An-Answers

Tags: discussion, answers

As common with a lot of other SE sites we have a lot of newcomers posting questions and comments as answers to existing questions. Before deleting these posts I usually comment the following for them to notice:

> Hi and welcome to expats.SE! Please note that this is a Questions&Answers site and not a forum, and this doesn't provide an answer. You can [search for similar questions](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/tour)

I was wondering if this standard notice can be made a bit more helpful and/or welcoming to newcomers, in order to make them - hopefully - stay on the site.

Comment: Reads well to me.  It happens so much on travel that it's usually just a 'please don't post a question in the box labelled 'answer'.